# Java Error Page Configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, error-handling

I have created a 404 page and am currently testing it with a simple page request that I know does not exist. This code will show the error page I have made (aka the result I want).

```
<!-- CONFIGURATION FOR ERROR PAGES -->
<error-page>
    <!--<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>-->
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/videoNotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

However, this code will show the apache tomcat default error page

```
<!-- CONFIGURATION FOR ERROR PAGES -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <!--<error-code>404</error-code>-->
    <location>/videoNotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

Any ideas why this is occurring, or what I could try to maybe fix this problem? Even though option 1 works, I prefer option 2 because I do not want to have a specific error page for each exception type.

Comment: by _apache tomcat default error page_ you mean default 404 page right ? or 500 internal server error ? 
can you see any exception trace in your tomcat console ? and can you confirm what http status code you are receiving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`404` and `java.lang.Throwable` are two very different error conditions triggered under different circumstances. the `404` like you've tested yourself is triggered by requesting a non-existent/unreachable resource and the `java.lang.Throwable` is an error condition that occurs as a result of an internal server/programming error, and it's represented by the http status code `500`. This condition, you cannot simulate by simply accessing an unreachable resource; the nature of `4xx` status codes generally is that they're thrown before the request even gets to your  web application while the `500` series error codes are mostly web app generated. The only way to test for this is to throw an instance of throwable `Exception` or `Error` *within* your web application code.

In the end, you will have to have two separate `error-page` definitions, one for container-related errors (essentially the `4xx` status codes) and another for the `500`/`throwable` type error conditions